# Why is my axios resulting in an [object Object]

Tags: javascript, axios

```
var sendButton = document.getElementById("send-button");

  sendButton.onclick = () => {
    axios.get('https://9spa57.nfshost.com/simple/messages/68').then((message) => {
      alert(message);
    })
  }
```

This results in an alert saying [object Object]

i tried a few things but nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(message))`

Comment: But just use `console.log` instead, not `alert`...